Why in Blender, low metallic fades color while V-Ray does not?
I got a simple sword model in Cycles, but rendering result was wrong.

Parts of the object faded color, mainly where metallic map was nearly black(nearly 0).
Unlink the metallic map and input 1.0 in metallic, rendered correctly.
But blender4.2 manual says: “The metal component is opaque and only reflect lights.”
I tried it in V-ray, the same metalmap works correctly.

Why in Blender does low metallic fades color, just as my following pic, but V-Ray not?
Is this a bug in Blender?



Did you remember to set "non-color" on the metallic map? Is the V-ray expected data the same format as Blender expected data? Blender expects values between 0 and 1, it's not usual, but some image formats such as TIF accept float values going to infinity.


Already set "non-color".     2. I tried both tga and jpg texture, the problem was still there. Maybe something else was wrong.


you have 3 sun lights with 10, 15 and 15 strength + the Specular IOR Level of the Principle BSDF is 2.0. The default value is 0.5. As a result, the diffuse colors are overexposed. Turn down the lights and specular value.

Thanks! I got it, now it's correct.

Solved, the Specular IOR Level was set too high. That's why color faded.
Thanks for Blunder's comment!
